# How to display a specific HTML element if the page is embedded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to show a small watermark on my website if someone uses an `<iframe>` of the URL and don’t want to show the HTML part if no `<iframe>` usage is detected.

JavaScript part

```
<script>
if(window != window.top) {
  // if true I want to show the HTML else nothing
};
</script>
```

HTML part that I want to show

```
<a href="https://example.com" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5px; text-align: center; width: 100%;" target="_blank">example.com</a>
```

How would I hide or display this HTML element?

Comment: You added _“I am sorry, that I am a newbie in coding.”_, but that actually adds nothing to the question to make it clear. A specific problem statement or question was missing, e.g. _“How would I hide or display this HTML element?”_. You can refer to [ask] which helps you write your questions more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the HTML `display:none` to hide as default behaviour and give it an `id="watermark"`:

```
<a href="https://example.com" id="watermark" style="display:none; position: fixed; bottom: 5px; text-align: center; width: 100%;" target="_blank">example.com</a>
```

The javascript could look like this:

```
if(window!=window.top) {
    document.getElementById('watermark').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     document.getElementById('watermark').style.display = 'none';
});});
</script>
 <a href="https://example.com" id="watermark"  target="_blank">example.com</a>
<button>Click to hide</button>
```